# Интегрировать в сайт диалоги между посетителями

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, шаблоны, конструктор

необходимо создать сайт с возможностью внутреннего общения его пользователей. По принципу blablacar, где зарегистрированные пользователи могут вступать в диалоги друг с другом. Возможно знаете какие-нибудь готовые решения или конструкторы сайтов с такой возможностью?

Comment: если сервер nginx установите модуль long polling и на нем уже все сделайте. Либо как вариант, посмотреть как устроины лс на сайтах, либо чаты уже на готовых движках и их переписать под себя.

Comment: Ещё вариант websocket или ajax